# Slice method not deleting all the duplicates

Tags: javascript

So I got this function which I want to remove all of the duplicates, but the .splice() method ain't functioning as it should, any ideas?

```js
const removeDuplicateds = (arr)=>{

    for (let i=0; i <arr.length ; i++){
        for (let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
            if (arr[i]=== arr[j]){
                arr.splice(j,1);
            }
           
        }
    }
    return console.log(arr);
}

removeDuplicateds([1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]);
```

The result: `(7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1]`
There are 14 1's and should be deleted 13, but it leaves 3, and I don't have any clue why
Thanks!

p.s: I know there's ways more easy to do the 'eliminate duplicates' thing (filter or reduce from EM6) but I'm new and wanted to know how the nested for worked (maybe not the best exercise for it)

Comment: everytime you use `.splice()` it removes an item from the array your iterating which throws off your counter. I would not recommend this method for removing duplicates.

Comment: The array `.length` changes every time you use `.splice` so your inner loop doesn't iterate the correct number of times. You can start your outer loop at the last index and work backwards to avoid this issue or simply use `array.filter()` to filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it as a pile of books. You remove a book from the middle the books above it move downward. So you finger was on the 5th book, the book that was the 6th is now the 5th. You keep your finger at the new 5th book, but you do not look at it. And you then look at the next book (6th) which was originally the 7th book in the pile. So if the "new 5th book" was one that should have been removed you ignored it.

Every time you remove an item the next item in the array shifts down one to fill that void. Since you already checked that spot, you ignore it and move on. So you would need to move back a spot when you remove it.

```js
const removeDuplicateds = (arr) => {

    for (let i=0; i <arr.length ; i++){
        for (let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
            if (arr[i]=== arr[j]){
                arr.splice(j,1);
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(removeDuplicateds([1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]));
```

How most people would solve it with this 2 loop method would be to do the second loop in reverse order.

```js
const removeDuplicateds = (arr) => {

    for (let i=0; i <arr.length ; i++){
        for (let j = arr.length - 1; j > i; j--){
            if (arr[i]=== arr[j]){
                arr.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(removeDuplicateds([1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]));
```

And what most people would do to dedupe the array

```js
const removeDuplicateds = (arr) => {
  return [...new Set(arr)];
};


console.log(removeDuplicateds([1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]))
```

Comment: What a great explanation (the books thing). If anyone has any doubt about it, just try to do the iteration on paper, it will help a lot. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

The array `.length` changes every time you use `.splice` so your inner loop doesn't iterate the correct number of times. You can start your outer loop at the last index and work backwards to avoid this issue or simply use `array.filter()` to filter out the duplicates.

```js
const removeDuplicateds = (arr)=>{

    for (let i=arr.length-1;i>-1 ; i--){
        for (let j=i-1; j>-1; j--){
            if (arr[i]=== arr[j]){
                arr.splice(j,1);
            }
           
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
}

removeDuplicateds([1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]);
```